# How to fix error Code bin root/go/bin not a valid identifier?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, snap

Trying to install chainlink on my laptop I had to install go. Doing so i think i have done something wrong and now i having error message each time I open ubuntu terminal which contents the following:

```
-bash: export: `Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Code/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/go/bin': not a valid identifier
```

is there a way to remove/delete these or to fix the error full stop,please?

Comment: Is this a question about programming?

Comment: it is about setting up environment i guess @possum

Comment: Don't cross-post the same question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722389/330217 https://askubuntu.com/q/1437006/1186757 https://stackoverflow.com/q/74191044/10622916